# How can I read a byte array file of strings?

Tags: python, string, utf-8

There is a file with following contents:

```
b'prefix:input_text'
b'oEffect:PersonX \xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xac\xd9\x86\xda\xaf ___ \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb2\xdb\x8c \xd9\x85\xdb\x8c \xda\xa9\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf'
b'oEffect:PersonX \xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xac\xd9\x86\xda\xaf ___ \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb2\xdb\x8c \xd9\x85\xdb\x8c \xda\xa9\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf'
```

This is my try to read the lines and convert them to readable utf characters, but still it shows the same strings in the output file:

```
f = open(input_file, "rb")
for x in f:
  inpcol.append(x.decode('utf-8'))

f = open(pred_file, "r")
for x in f:
  predcol.append(x)

f = open(target_file, "r")
for x in f:
  targcol.append(x)
data =[]
for i in tqdm(range(len(targcol))):
  data.append([inpcol[i],targcol[i],predcol[i]])

pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["input_text","target_text","pred_text"]).to_csv(f"{path}/merge_{predfile}.csv", encoding="utf-8")
print("Done!")
```

The output file is:

```
,input_text,target_text,pred_text
0,"b'prefix:input_text'
","target_text
","ﺏﺭﺎﯾ ﺩﺮﮐ ﻮﻀﻌﯿﺗ
"
1,"b'xNeed:PersonX \xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xac\xd9\x86\xda\xaf ___ \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb2\xdb\x8c \xd9\x85\xdb\x8c \xda\xa9\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf'
","ﺞﻨﮕﯾﺪﻧ
","ﺏﺭﺎﯾ ﭗﯾﺩﺍ ﮎﺭﺪﻧ ﯽﮐ ﺖﯿﻣ
"
```

As you see, the problem exists for input line but not for target and prediction lines (however scrambled but that's okay)

Comment: The contents of the file are unclear. Please edit your question and copy its contents (from with in a text editor) then paste that into it.

Comment: I opened the file with `vim`, they are just unicode chars. Its what vim shows. However, they are actually in Persian alphabet, something like علی به مدرسه رفت

Comment: Then paste the Unicode characters from it into your question — because that is what must be read from the file.

Comment: @martineau They are as it shows, there is no diferrence. However, the target and prediction files are shown in Persian, but the input file is as is.

Comment: Well, it seems very odd that the contents of the file appears to be in Python [`bytes` string literal syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) because of the `b'` prefix and ending `'` quote character. Perhaps you could put a copy of the file somewhere (like [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/)) and put a link to it into you question.

Comment: if you read it as bytes then you will see numbers - char codes in UTF8 - and this is normal. If you will read it in text mode then you may see expected text - if you have font with these chars and if your console can display text in UTF-8. As for me file is OK but you have to use correct tools to see chars.

Comment: if you see prefix `b` and `' '` when you read in text mode then you wrote it in wrong way. If you use `str(bytes)` to convert bytes to string then you get it with prefix.

Comment: @furas if you mean `f = open(input_file, "r")
    for x in f:
      inpcol.append(str(x))
``` it also didn't work.

Comment: first reduce code to important elements `f = open(input_file, "r")` , `print( f.read() )`. We don't need pandas, tqdm for this problem

Comment: if you read with "r" then you read in text mode and you don't need `str()` to convert string to the same string. And if you see text with `b' '` then it means you wrote it in wrong way. You converted bytes to string using `str()` - which adds `b' '` - and you wrote this string. You should use `.decode("utf-8")` before writing in text mode. Or you should write it directly in bytes mode `wb`

Comment: `f.read()` prints `b'xNeed:PersonX \xd8\xa8\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xdb\x8c \xda\xa9\xd8\xb1\xdb\x8c\xd8\xb3\xd9\x85\xd
8\xb3 \xd8\xa7\xd8\xb2 ___ \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb2\xd8\xaf\xdb\x8c\xd8\xaf \xd9\x85\xdb\x8c
 \xda\xa9\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf'
`

Comment: @furas I didn't write it I use a neural network model which generates those files, it has no problem with two other files but the input file. Anyways, I guess there must be a method to convert them to readable characters.

Comment: it shows that file was written incorrectly. Someone made `str(bytes)` isntead of `bytes.decode('utf-8'). if you can't correct code which write it then you may have to correct text which you get

Comment: you have to crop `b' '` - `text[2:-1]` - and convert it back to bytes using `.encode('raw_unicode_escape')` and convert again to string using `.decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems someone wrote bytes in wrong way. Someone used `str(bytes)` instead of `bytes.decode('utf-8')`. Or maybe code was created for `Python 2` which treats bytes and strings in different way then `Python 3`.

---

if you can correct code which write it then you have to fix text

```
text = "b'oEffect:PersonX \xd8\xaf\xd8\xb1 \xd8\xac\xd9\x86\xda\xaf ___ \xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb2\xdb\x8c \xd9\x85\xdb\x8c \xda\xa9\xd9\x86\xd8\xaf'"
```

crop `b' '`

```
text = text[2:-1]
```

convert back to `bytes` using special encoding `'raw_unicode_escape'`

```
text = text.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

and convert to `string` correctly

```
text = text.decode()
```

And now

```
print(text)
```

gives me

```
oEffect:PersonX در جنگ ___ بازی می کند
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems it has codes converted to strings with double slashes like `b'\\xd8'` but `print()` may display it as single slash  but `print(repr())` may show it with double slashes.

It may need more `decode/encode` to convert it correctly.

```
text = "b'xNeed:PersonX \\xd8\\xaf\\xd8\\xb1 \\xd8\\xac\\xd9\\x86\\xda\\xaf'"
print(repr(text))
print(text)

text = text[2:-1]
text = text.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
text = text.decode('unicode_escape')
text = text.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
text = text.decode()
print(text)
```

Comment: It prints the expected output, however I am trying to do these in the loop of reading file, still not succeed, i try more

Comment: first you can use `print(..)` and `print(type(..))` to check what you have in variables when you read in loop. I can't test your file and code so I can't help more.

Comment: Where I should do these? I tried in the loop  for reading file with no luck, I also tried in writing no luck `for i in tqdm(range(len(targcol))):
      text = inpcol[i]
      text = text[2:-1]
      text = text.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
      text = text.decode()
      data.append([text,targcol[i],predcol[i]])
`

Comment: in read loop the type is `str` also note it prints each line without quotation, is it effective?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't suceed! I don't know if you put them in a file you would succeed or not, anywyas, thanks, I vote it up

Comment: you could use `print()` to see value in `text` after every step. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: Sorry I did but it just repeats those slahses... And Hey, most programmers do know these dirty stuff!

Comment: do you see single slashes - `\xd8\xaf` - or double slashes - `\\xd8\\xaf` ? With double slashes it will convert them only to single slashes and it may need more `decode/encode` to convert it correctly.

Comment: check text with `print(repr(text))`

Comment: I added code which convert it when there is `\\` in text.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wish I could upvoted it more...